# Serial communication from USB to Colab Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, google-colaboratory, pyserial

Is there any python library that could read serial usb connections on google colab notebook?
So basically, local usb to remote server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible as of last year (when the Colab IFrame policy was changed). You can see an example Colab notebook developed by Arm that [connects to a Raspberry Pi Pico here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ArmDeveloperEcosystem/ml-audio-classifier-example-for-pico/blob/main/ml_audio_classifier_example_for_pico.ipynb).